# Partitions and Indexes, in which cases should be used

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, index

I know some knowledges:

- Partitions used to achieve better performance (like described in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/manisblog/easy-table-partitions-with-sql-server-2008) article)
- And indexes used to increase performance in selection operations.

And as result my question: in which cases i should use indexes and in which cases i should use partitioned tables.

In other words what should be better in different operations(selections,deletions,updates) indexes or partitioning of table, and why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy: you should always use indexes.

Partitioning for performance is probably the most misunderstood myth out there. When you partition, the best you can hope for is on-par performance with a non-partitioned table. And yes, that is *including* partition elimination enhancements. Reducing table scans to partition scans because of missing indexes is simply *not the answer*. Replacing table scans with index seeks or index range scans it is a *much better* the answer.

Partitioning is a *great* feature for data maintenance and administration and for efficient ETL switch-in and switch-out operations. For a good discussion of pros and cons of partitioning, see [How To Decide if You Should Use Table Partitioning](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/).

Comment: +1 @Remus Partitioning should only be used after careful evaluation. See Kendra Little's blog on whether to partition: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/ If you don't know what you're doing with partitioning, performance will go south quickly.

Comment: +1 Neither is a replacement for the other.  Two very different technologies for two very different outcomes.